# python tarfile - extract file using its symlink from archive

Tags: python-2.7, tarfile

I can extract a regular file using its full path.

```
tar.extract("filepath", targetdir)
```

I have a tar archive with below structure, where I want to extract a file using its symbolic link in the tar:

```
Base dir
|
--->testDir/.../testFile
--->testSymlink
```

How can I extract the "testFile" using "testSymlink" ?